# How to access multi-index h5 data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an h5 generated by deeplabcut.

I need to extract the values from it but am having some troubles doing it in a way that makes sense.

For instance, I have this:

```
scorer    Test_Scorer
bodyparts                                      eye1                               eye2
coords                                            x           y likelihood           x           y likelihood
0                                        363.874268  230.710175        1.0  361.621918  281.668335        1.0
1                                        364.350006  231.054901        1.0  361.714630  281.743195        1.0
```

Which happens when printing my `table` after reading it with `pd.read_hdf`

I know I can use `scorer = table.keys()[0][0]` and that will retrieve the scorer value seen above.

I need to get things like `likelihood` `eye1` x and y coords. But for all the bodyparts.

Is it possible to get a list of the bodyparts? And then using that list, get the coordinates?

I need a way to get this data using keywords not index values. I though by nature this was the design of h5 files making them superior to say csv.

Is the only way to access data inside the h5 structure via a for loop on the keys and the subset of keys?

The keys are type tuple, and I know they are in this order `names=['scorer', 'bodyparts', 'coords'])` by doing `print(table.keys())`

I don't know if I am making this harder then necessary, but there is like nothing in the documentation for deeplabcut nor panda for retrieving the desired information.

Per request: `table.head().to_dict()`

```
{('Test_Scorer', 'eye1', 'x'): {0: 363.874267578125, 1: 364.3500061035156, 2: 364.3739318847656, 3: 364.43511962890625, 4: 364.4678649902344}, ('Test_Scorer', 'eye1', 'y'): {0: 230.71017456054688, 1: 231.05490112304688, 2: 230.77639770507812, 3: 230.80335998535156, 4: 230.92771911621094}, ('Test_Scorer', 'eye1', 'likelihood'): {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0}, ('Test_Scorer', 'eye2', 'x'): {0: 361.6219177246094, 1: 361.7146301269531, 2: 361.7553405761719, 3: 361.8115539550781, 4: 361.8218688964844}, ('Test_Scorer', 'eye2', 'y'): {0: 281.6683349609375, 1: 281.7431945800781, 2: 281.96533203125, 3: 281.9486999511719, 4: 281.86212158203125}, ('Test_Scorer', 'eye2', 'likelihood'): {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0}}
```

Comment: can you do `table.head().to_dict()` and add the output to your questions? It will make it easier understand the structure of the frame

Comment: @Yo_Chris added.

Comment: @Yo_Chris If I am reading this correctly, the key is of type tuple, and the "values" are of type set. Is this correct?

Comment: It looks like it is a multiindex of tuples, which is standard. What are you looking to accomplish: flatten to a 1D column structure or just access values in the frame? Here is how you can flatter: `new_df = table['Test_Scorer']; new_df.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in new_df.columns]`

Comment: @Yo_Chris ultimately, access data values in the frame via bodypart and x, y, or liklihood. I think flattening will give me that though.

Comment: Or are you looking for something like this: `table['Test_Scorer'].stack(1).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`

Comment: Let me try this out

Comment: @Yo_Chris, can you make an answer. Your flatten comment will work with modification. This gets me what I need though and is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten you multi-indexed columns using list comprehension and f-strings (python 3.6 or greater):

```
new_df = table['Test_Scorer']
new_df.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in new_df.columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just index it like this: `Dataframe['Test_Scorer']['eye1']['x']`, or alternatively: `Dataframe['Test_Scorer','eye1','x']`.

Perhaps also check out this example notebook on how to deal with DeepLabCut data: https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DLCutils/blob/master/Demo_loadandanalyzeDLCdata.ipynb

Comment: Thanks for the link.

I do have one question for whoever, how could I get the scorer and list of bodyparts?

Comment: Normally you get it from the config.yaml file that defines the DLC project. However, you can of course also extract them from the pandas array. For instance: ``scorer=Dataframe.columns.get_level_values(0)[0]`` gives you the scorer name and 
``bodyparts=Dataframe.columns.get_level_values(1)`` the bodyparts (this is also in the linked notebook)